# brother scanner mfc-7360 install ubuntu 16-10

Tags: networking, drivers, scanner, brother

I have been the happy owner of a brother mfc-7360 for some years now and after each ubuntu update I have to reinstall the printer and the scanner on my network. Oke I admit not the easiest task but still I managed everytime, till now, not now after 16.10.
I'm not sure though if the update is the problem.

What did i do:

1. installed the Brother brscan4 drivers according to the Brothers guidelines after i installed the printer part, which functions as should.

   ```
   sudo dpkg  -i  --force-all brscan4-0.4.4-1.amd64.deb.
   ```
2. checked installation:

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep Brother:  
   ii  brscan-skey                                     0.2.4-1                                     amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool  
   ii  brscan4                                         0.4.4-1                                     amd64        Brother Scanner Driver  
   ii  cupswrappermfc7360n:i386                        2.0.4-2                                     i386         Brother MFC7360N CUPS wrapper driver  
   ii  mfc7360nlpr:i386                                2.1.0-1                                     i386         Brother MFC-7360N LPR driver  
   ii  printer-driver-brlaser                          3-5                                         amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers  
   ii  printer-driver-ptouch                           1.4.2-2                                     amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
   ```
3. configurated brscan4:

   ```
   brsaneconfig4 -a name=SCANNER model=MFC-7360N ip=192.168.0.209
   ```
4. checked the configuration:

   ```
   brsaneconfig4 -q | grep SCANNER:  
     0 SCANNER             "MFC-7360N"         I:192.168.0.209
   ```
5. started `xsane`, but this doesn't find the scanner.

---

When I turned to the printer/scanner itself, I reset up the netwerk setting:

1. tcp-ip:

   ```
   startmethode: auto (ip adres is reserved for that mac-adres by my router)   
   ip-adres: 192.168.0.209   
   subnet: 255.255.255.0  
   gateway: 192.168.0.1  
   nodename: as was: (br-mac-cb)  
   wins config and server as set, not used  
   Dns: primairy: 192.168.0.1, secundairy: empty  
   apipa: as was  
   IPv6: as was
   ```
2. Ethernet: auto
3. status: active 100b-FD
4. Mac-address = as was

When I press on the scan function on the printer it says connect cable. 
I triple checked the network cable, no problem there. Also I pinged the printer and all pings were accepted withing normal time range. Which is accepted as the printer does work over the network.

At this moment I really have no idea what else to try or test.

Has anyone an idea or experience with this problem?

Kind regards, Matt

Comment: I have a Brother DCP-J552DW and I could never use the "scan-button" on the device. I always use `simple-scan` from within my linux. I think that's not working because the PC need to register itself in some kind of way at the printer and that function is not implemented in the linux-driver. BTW: There is an install script on the brother website which automatically downloads and installs the .deb-packages.

Comment: thank you for repliing! for simple-scan counts the same thing, it doens't find the scanner. which was kinda expected as is has the same back-end as xsane. still was worth the try. also, i agree the scan button never worked, but it never said "check cable" at least not as long as i can remember, but ifso, i think i would've.

Comment: I haven't used the scanning feature in my Brother DCP-7065DN for a couple of years but if I remember correctly you need a program running on the computer for when the "scan button" is pressed. I believe there is one in Windows but not one in Linux (unfortunately).

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i believe the question is misunderstood. as said the scan button never worked and i don't expect it too. the problem is that xsane and simple-scan for that matter do not see the scanner while tjhe drivers are installed and configurated while the printer works so mechanically the is nothing wrong /disconnected and i never had the check cable issue before.